# Client side Blazor: Slow load of a resource

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, blazor-webassembly, openweathermap

I have some lines of code, that worked well in Xamarin.Forms, but it performs very poorly in Client-side Blazor.

This is the code:


`string s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Properties.Resources.city_list);
List _cityList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List>(s).ToList();`

the city_list is a huge list from OpenWeatherMap that is containing all the cities around the globe.
Later I want to display this list as options in a select, so I would like to keep it on the client-side. The code now is very slow, it takes minutes to run it. Do you have an idea, how can I make it faster?

Thank you in advance
Janos

Update:
I removed the Take(20), because that is not part of the problem. I want to get the full list.

The city_list is a text file in Json format. I added it as Resource, so it is a byte array in this code.

Comment: What format is `Properties.Resources.city_list` in?

Comment: You are de-serializing the JSON payload containing EVERY City and then take the first 20 entries from that list, this is predestined to run slow. You should retrieve the  data from API when necessary only (i.e. request the first 20).

Comment: Which version of Blazor are you using? If with .net6 , Have you tried to use AOT to see if it works better, of course this only works with published version, but it would probably go a bit faster(Not that it's the definitive solution to your issue). Also, have a look here, this might help(Github of dotnet concerning this issue) https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/40386.

Comment: @Beltway: If I will not find a suitable solution to this problem, than I will use an API, but since this worked well with Xamarin forms on an android device, I guessed, that it will work with Blazor as well.

Comment: @Shuryno: I used .netcore 3.1, but I will try it with 6.0.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is related to very slow string parsing in Blazor. Yesterday I hit the same problem with parsing a json data of 6 mb. Even with the small json data the delays between page landings are noticable to eye. In a non-Blazor .NET application parsing is done really fast though.

So I figured out whether the problem is about json parsing or in general string parsing. I tested the below code on a reguler Console app and on Blazor WebAssembly. The difference is huge: Console(768 milliseconds), Blazor 45(seconds). Seems like this is an issue with web assembly because javascript parsing is also fast. This problem has been around for sometime. See also here.
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/40386

Well this being said even though this is a very simple problem it completely invalidates Blazor as a production ready framework.

This was tested on .NET 6 both for Console and Blazor.

```
public class StringParsePerfTest
{
    private string Text { get; set; } = "";
    public StringParsePerfTest()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            if (i % 3 == 0) Text += "|";
            else Text += "a";
        }
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        var start = DateTime.Now;
        start= DateTime.Now;
        for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            var splitted = Text.Split("|");
        }
        var end = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine($"{(end - start).TotalMilliseconds}");
    }
}
```